# Full Server Backup procedure

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How to take full server backup ? So that I can restore Server as it is in case of any failure.

Comment: You're going to need to specify a lot more information. Where your server is, what OS is it running, what sort of access to it do you have, and so on..

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for any backup solution that can do [Bare Metal Restore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bare-metal_restore). The documentation the software comes with should provide you with enough instructions to make it work.

A list of backup software products can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backup_software)